# how to append hadoop job id to hive query result file?

Tags: hadoop, hive

I have a hive query insert overwrite to local file system. My query is as the following:

insert overwrite local directory `/home/test/dds`

```
select col1, col2 from test_table where query_ymd='2011-05-15' or query_ymd='2011-05-16' or query_ymd='2011-05-17';
```

It generates 2 files:

```
.000000_0.crc
000000_0
```

I would like the output to be:

```
attempt_201303210330_19069_r_000000_0
attempt_201303210330_19069_r_000000_0.crc
```

How can I config the hive server or query?

Answer (score 0):

one HQL has some jobs,not only one.So,you can not do this.